# Getting left join table sum incorrect

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table

`teams_users` and `summary_coins`

teams_users data example

```
id team_id user_id
1   1       1
2   1       2
3   2       3
```

summary_coins data example

```
id    team_id    get_count 
 1     2          10         
 2     2           5
```

Desire output :

```
id     team_id   total_user   get_count 
1       2             1        15
2       1             2         0
```

Here I am trying to get all teams_user count with sum of coins teams. I have tried below sql

```
SELECT 
    teams_users.team_id,
    count(teams_users.user_id) as team_users_count,
    sum(summary_coins.get_count) as get_coins_count
from teams_users
    LEFT JOIN summary_coins 
    on summary_coins.team_id = teams_users.team_id
group by summary_coins.team_id,teams_users.team_id
order by teams_users.team_id ASC
```

I am getting team users correctly but sum of coins from summary table I am getting wrong value

```
Team_id  team_users_count   coins_sum
3        150                 300
4        22                   77
```

For team_id 3 I have 30 coins, but in query I am getting 300.

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana I have update my question.

Comment: It's quite possible. For example, when coins count also depends on user_id which is ignored by the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way:

```
SELECT 
    teams_users.team_id,
    count(teams_users.user_id) as team_users_count,
    get_coins_count
from teams_users
LEFT JOIN ( select team_id ,sum(summary_coins.get_count) get_coins_count
            from summary_coins 
            group by team_id
    ) summary_coins
    on summary_coins.team_id = teams_users.team_id
group by teams_users.team_id , get_coins_count
order by teams_users.team_id ASC
```

or more readabale way:

```
select * from ( 
    select team_id , count(*) total_user
    from teams_users
    group by team_id
) u
join (
    select team_id ,sum(summary_coins.get_count) get_coins_count
    from summary_coins 
    group by team_id
) c
on c.team_id = u.team_id
order by team_id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Team_users should be aggregated first

```
SELECT 
    tu.team_id, tu.team_users_count,
    sum(summary_coins.get_count) as get_coins_count
from (
  select team_id,
      count(user_id) as team_users_count
  from teams_users
  group by team_id
) tu
LEFT JOIN summary_coins 
    on summary_coins.team_id = tu.team_id
group by tu.team_id, tu.team_users_count
order by tu.team_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

> ### Table Users
>
> ```
> id  Group
> 1   A
> 2   A
> 3   B
> 4   B
> ```
>
> ### Table Summary
>
> ```
> idGroup    Coins
> A          100
> B          150
> ```

When you query:

```
select * from users,summary where users.Group=summary.idGroup
```

You get:

> ### Query Users-Summary
>
> ```
> id  Group  Coins
> 1   A      100
> 2   A      100
> 3   B      150
> 4   B      150
> ```

When you query:

```
select group,count(*),sum(coins) from users,summary where users.Group=summary.idGroup group by users.group, summary.coins
```

You get:

> ### Query Users-Summary
>
> ```
> Group  Count(*) Sum(Coins)
> A      2        200
> B      2        300
> ```

Then...